# Programmatically change individual ListViewItem layout

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, listviewitem

I have a `ListView` with a `GridView` in it:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewPersons" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons, Mode=OneWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4,4,4,4" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="gridViewPersons">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Enabled">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="true" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="142" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Age}" Width="142" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Gender"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Gender}" Width="142" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I want to be able to programmatically change each of the `ListViewItem`s (or the rows in the grid) backgrounds or foregrounds to any color I want, for instance

```
listViewPersons.Items[0].Background = Brush.Red;
listViewPersons.Items[1].Background = Brush.Blue;
listViewPersons.Items[2].Background = Brush.Green
```

I know the previous lines of code don't work, but it pretty much explains what I want to achieve. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this approach:

1. Bind ForegroundColor and Background color to a property in Persons.  Let's call this property PersonStatus, and set its type to a status enum, just for this example.
2. Ensure that this Persons implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), and the setter for this property raises a [ProperyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event.  The property will look like this:

   ```
   public Status PersonStatus
   {
       get
       {
           return status;
       }
       set
       {
           if (value != status)
           {
               status= value;
               if (PropertyChanged != null)
                   PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PersonStatus"));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that takes the type of Status and returns a Brushes.Black, Brushes.Red, etc.  Something like this:

   ```
   public class StatusToColorConverter : IValueConverter 
   {
       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
           if (targetType != typeof(Status))
               throw new InvalidOperationException("targetType must be Status");

           Status status = (Status)value;

           switch (status)
           {
               case Status.New:
                   return Brushes.Black;
               case Status.Professional:
                   return Brushes.Blue;
               case Status.Delete:
                   return Brushes.Red;
               default:
                   return Brushes.Black;
           }
       }

       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       } 
   }
   ```